# Como compilar en Python 2 ó 3 así como se compila en C, para crear el archivo ejecutable (Plataforma windows)

Tags: python, compilar

Cuando se compila en lenguaje C y/o C++, se crea un archivo ejecutable independiente y se puede correr en cualquier otra computadora.
En lenguaje Python ya sea la versión 2 o el 3 cuando se quiere correr el código fuente, se corre por interpretación, pero no deja un archivo que se pueda correr solo sin instalar el compilador. La misma pregunta me surge para el basic en openoffice. Soy una persona autodidacta en el tema. Gracias

Comment: Tono, bienvenido a SOes. Es posible que tu pregunta pueda ser considerada muy amplia, ya que aqui tratamos de resolver problemas especificos. Te recomiendo ver el [help] para saber mas del sitio y de la tematica apropiada de este. Como mero comentario, te recomiendo que investigues de pyinstaller, que creo que puede resolver tu problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Python como sabrás es un lenguaje que requiere de un intérprete para que sea ejecutable, lo cual es una ventaja en muchos casos, pero también puede ser un inconveniente. Por ejemplo si vas a ejecutar tu "script" en un ordenador donde no se haya instalado el intérprete entonces no podrás ejecutarlo. Si tu sistema operativo es una distribución de Linux, entonces seguramente lo tengas instalado ya que viene por defecto, al menos en las distribuciones más populares. Pero si tu ordenador es Windows entonces tienes que instalar el intérprete previamente.

En este tutorial os voy a explicar cómo teniendo nuestro "script.py" podemos generar un ejecutable (.exe) que lleve incorporado el interprete para que podamos ejecutarlo en cualquier ordenador Windows tenga o no el interprete.

Los requisitos para seguir el tutorial son los siguientes:

Tener el archivo.py que queremos generar.
Tener instalado el intérprete de Python en nuestro ordenador.
Instalar Py2Exe.
Para instalar el intérprete --> Introducción a Python Página de Py2Exe --> Usa este enlace para ir a py2exe.org
Importante: instalar py2exe como administrador
Ahora que ya tenéis todo lo necesario para seguir hasta el final el tutorial comenzamos.
Primer Paso:

Creamos un archivo llamado setup.py en la misma carpeta donde esté el archivo .py que queramos convertir a .exe. El contenido del archivo setup.py debe contener información sobre el nombre del archivo, algún comentario, versión del programa, etc. Un ejemplo de lo que sería un setup.py bastante completo sería:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from distutils.core import setup 
import py2exe 

setup(name="Nombre ejecutable", 
version="1.0", 
description="Breve descripcion", 
author="autor", 
author_email="email del autor", 
url="url del proyecto", 
license="tipo de licencia", 
scripts=["nuestroArchivo.py, 
console=["nuestroArchivo.py, 
options={"py2exe": {"bundle_files": 1}}, 
zipfile=None,
)
```

Este ejemplo lo podéis tomar como plantilla y rellenar con vuestra información, lo más importante es que en scripts=["nuestroArchivo.py  y en scripts=["nuestroArchivo.py  debéis cambiar nuestroArchivo.py por el nombre de vuestro archivo.

Segundo Paso:

Abrir la consola de Windows (símbolo de sistema). En Windows 8.1 lo más rápido es hacer click con el botón derecho en el logo de Windows y pichar en "símbolo de sistema" cómo podéis ver en la imagen.

Una vez que la hemos abierto debemos debemos llegar hasta la carpeta donde tenemos nuestros dos archivos Python. Os recuerdo que para acceder a una carpeta usamos cd miCarpeta  y para ver que carpetas hay en el directorio donde estemos usamos dir .

Tercer paso:

Una vez que ya hemos llegado al directorio objetivo. Introducimos la siguiente sentencia: setup.py py2exe . Nos empezará a salir información en la consola de archivos que está creando. Algo así:

Cuando haya finalizado entonces tendremos nuestro archivo .exe en una carpeta llama "dist". El programa genera 2 carpetas una llamada "dist" y otro llamada "build" pero con el setup.py que hemos usado nos basta con quedarnos sólo con el archivo ejecutable.

El resultado deber este:

Comment: Gracias Jose, lo voy a probar.

Comment: Gracias por la busqueda  https://geekytheory.com/generar-un-ejecutable-exe-a-partir-de-un-py/